# Yii CGridview Filter Datepicker

Tags: filter, yii, cgridview

I have already read the forum about make custom cgridview.. I want to make filter use datetimepicker.

Datetimepicker:

I can include already the datetimepicker, but when I choose the date, it became error. :(.. 
My date datatype on database is 'timestamp'
[image: Date]
[image: Error]

This is the code

```
<?php
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Events'=>array('index'),
    'Manage',
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List Event','url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create Event','url'=>array('create')),
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('event-grid', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
?>

<h1>Manage Events</h1>

<p>
You may optionally enter a comparison operator (<b>&lt;</b>, <b>&lt;=</b>, <b>&gt;</b>, <b>&gt;=</b>, <b>&lt;&gt;</b>
or <b>=</b>) at the beginning of each of your search values to specify how the comparison should be done.
</p>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button btn')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'id'=>'event-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>"function(){jQuery('#event_date_search').datepicker({'dateFormat': 'yy-mm-dd'})}",
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'type' => 'raw',
            'name'=> 'event_image',
            'value' => 'CHtml::image("'.Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/uploads/event/$data->event_image", "event_image" ,array("width"=>100))',
            'filter'=> false,
        ),
        'event_name',
        array(
            'name' => 'event_date',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'filter'=>$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatepicker', array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'attribute'=>'event_date',
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'id' => 'event_date_search'
                ), 
                'options' => array(
                    'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd'
                )
            ), true)
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'published',
            'filter'=>CHtml::dropDownList('Event[published]', '',  
                array(
                    ''=>'',
                    '1'=>'Published',
                    '0'=>'Not Published',
                )
            ),
            'value' =>'($data->published==1)?"Published":"Not Published"',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); 

?>
```

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

You can change search() function of model class. It can be like this:

```
public function search() {
     ....
     $criteria->addCondition('DATE_FORMAT(time_field, \'%Y-%m-%d\') = ' . $this->time_field);
     ....
}
```

but it can be need to translate input value of $this->time_field.

Answer (score 0):

i had the exact same problem yesterday and for some unknown reason by moving the

`'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd'`

from option to htmloptions fixed my problem. to be honest i have it in both htmloptions and options and don't have any problems so far

```
'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'id' => 'event_date_search',
                    'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd'
                     ), 

 'options' => array(
                    'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd'
                   ),
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace your code

```
'options' => array(
   'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd'
)
```

with

```
'defaultOptions' => array(
   'showOn' => 'focus', 
   'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
   'showOtherMonths' => true,
   'selectOtherMonths' => true,
   'changeMonth' => true,
   'changeYear' => true,
   'showButtonPanel' => true,
)
```

Hope this help

For detail check this link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/318/using-cjuidatepicker-for-cgridview-filter/